# How to get .publishsettings for Web Deployable Web Role?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, webdeploy

I enabled the Web Deploy feature for my Web Role and deployed it.
But how can I get hold of the .publishsettings file so I can create a Publishing Profile for it?

[This 2 year old article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud/archive/2011/04/19/enabling-web-deploy-for-windows-azure-web-roles-with-visual-studio.aspx) states that it should have been created automatically, but I haven't got that in my profile manager.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was really behind the keyboard.

So the publishing profile is actually provisioned correctly and automatically to the Web project as the documentation states.

The problem and confusion was that I have a secondary web application in my Solution that I also publish to the same Web Role (referenced as an additional `Site` in the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file).
That Web Project does not get the Publishing Profile, and when I try to create a profile manually, it doesn't work since that (secondary) IIs instance is not configured for Web Deployment.

Oh well, back to the tedious Cloud Service deployment it is...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012 or greater, the server explorer to the left will have several Azure items.

Specifically the Windows Azure Compute is what we are looking for, right click on that and say 'add deployment environment'. You will then be prompted with a dialog that allows you to sign in and download publish settings file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get publishsettings file from the following link: https://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.aspx