# I can't publish to a cloud service on Windows Azure. I'm getting a security token validation error. How can I fix it?

Tags: .net, azure

I'm just trying to normally publish a package to a Windows Azure Cloud Service. I'm getting the folloing error. I'm using .NET 4.5.1 with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Any clue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the right deployment / environment setup in Visual Studio.  See this thread for more information [How to get .publishsettings for Web Deployable Web Role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884585/how-to-get-publishsettings-for-web-deployable-web-role)